# External network display for playing media

Tags: video, display, media, dlna

On my Windows 10 computer I was able to right click a media file (video) and choose "Play To ..." and then select my Sony Tv which was plugged into the network. The video would then play with the controls shown on the computer but the media being output on the television.

I am unsure of the specifics of how this worked. Perhaps the tv announced itself as a dlna monitor or something.

Is there any support for this sort of functionality on Linux? Even if it's not as tightly integrated. I don't mind using the console, etc but it would be great to be able to send media to the tv like I could from Windows if this is possible.